# Trac Using Database Authentication

Tags: python, mysql, apache, trac

Is it possible to use a database for authentication with Trac?
.htpasswd auth is not desired in this install.

Using Trac .11 and MySQL as the database. Trac is currently using the database, but provides no authentication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of the box, [Trac doesn't actually do its own authentication](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracAuthenticationIntroduction), it leaves it up to the web server. So, you've got a wealth of Apache-related options available to you. You could maybe look at something like [auth_mysql](http://sourceforge.net/projects/modauthmysql) to let you keep user credentials in a database.

Alternatively, take a look at the [AccountManagerPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin) on trac-hacks.org

Comment: This seems like the best way to go.

Comment: The document you are referring to is uncomplete and four years old.

Comment: Added link to alternative as this is now the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Account Manager Plugin with SessionStore](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin#SessionStore)

The AccountManagerPlugin offers several features for managing user accounts:

- allow users to register new accounts
- login via an HTML form instead of using HTTP authentication
- allow existing users to change their passwords or delete their accounts
- send a new password to users who’ve forgotten their password
- administration of user accounts

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin

Do the following on your trac.ini
[components]
; be sure to enable the component
acct_mgr.svnserve.* = enabled
acct_mgr.svnserve.svnservepasswordstore = enabled
; choose one of the hash methods
acct_mgr.pwhash.htdigesthashmethod = enabled
acct_mgr.pwhash.htpasswdhashmethod = enabled

[account-manager]
password_store = SvnServePasswordStore
password_file = /path/to/svn/repos/conf/passwd
; choose one of the hash methods
hash_method = HtDigestHashMethod
hash_method = HtPasswdHashMethod

Now trac will use user in the database